# Layer blur in flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter-layout, layer, blur

How to apply the Figma layer blur effect in a flutter what code to apply to get that circle in the image in code?
i have tried to apply radial gradient but results are different from the design is it possible to get this in flutter

Comment: Please attach the code of what you have tried

Comment: Provide a picture of what you're trying to achieve would be helpful